# Determining if a substring is contained within a string, case insensitively

Tags: c++, string, substring

I'm doing a challenge on HackerRank which involves finding the number of times a substring appears in a series of strings.  The user inputs how many strings they would like to test to see if they contain "hackerrank", insensitive to case.  I've pulled a method from another popular answer on here to convert a string to uppercase.  Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cctype>

std::string upperCase(std::string input) {
        for (std::string::iterator it = input.begin(); it != input.end(); ++ it)
                *it = toupper(*it);
        return input;
}

int main(){
        int numofStrings;
        std::cin >> numofStrings;
        std::string tweetString;
        int hackerRankOccurrences = 0;
        for (numofStrings; numofStrings>0; numofStrings--) {
                std::cin >> tweetString;
                bool found = upperCase(tweetString).find("HACKERRANK")!=std::string::npos;
                if (found) {
                        hackerRankOccurrences++;
                }               
        }
        std::cout << hackerRankOccurrences << std::endl;
}
```

The problem, in my understanding, is that this upperCase method returns every word of the input on a different line, e.g.:

> Hello, this is a sentence

becomes:

> HELLO,
>
> THIS
>
> IS
>
> A
>
> SENTENCE

This causes the for loop to iterate through every word in the string, decrementing the total user input numofStrings for every word used.

How can I get upperCase to return a single string / single line of output?

Comment: Did you try printing out `tweetString` before calling `upperCase()`?

Comment: First result for google `c++ get whole line cin`: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/13866/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally unrelated to `upperCase`, which is returning exactly the same size string you passed into it.  The fix, change:

```
std::cin >> tweetString;
```

to

```
getline(std::cin, tweetString);
```

Comment: Okay, I'm a dummy.  Thanks!